# How to get substring in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am fetching data from Api and showing it in FlatList but I want to show only limited string to the user not the whole text I am getting from the Api.

Below is the sample text I am getting from server.

```
 "Text": "Apu Nahasapeemapetilon - Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons."
```

Here I want to show data only till `-` after `-` I don't want this long data to show in Flatlist.Is there any way to get text only before `-` sign.

Below is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator,FlatList} from 'react-native';

const List = () => {

const[post,setPost] = useState([]);
const[isLoading,setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    
    const url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json';
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resp) => setPost(resp.RelatedTopics))
    .catch((err) => alert(err));
 },[]);

    return(

      <View>

            <FlatList 
            data = {post} 
            keyExtractor = {(item) => item.FirstURL} 
            renderItem = {({item}) => <Text>{item.Text}</Text>} />
      
      </View>
    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 testStyle:{
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent:"center",
     alignItems:"center"
   }
});

export default List;
```

Someone let me know how can I get desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When showing the text node in flatlist use slice method

eg
var a = "Apu Nahasapeemapetilon - Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons."

then

a.split('-', 1)[0]
will give "Apu Nahasapeemapetilon "

Comment: What is this `[0]` at the end of `a.split('-', 1)[0]`.

Comment: when you split it it becomes array and 0 is the index of first element of array if you print [1] this will give you the second part after hyphen

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Comment: Could you please tell how can I show `ActivityIndiacator`  before loading Flatlist I have initialed it to True but no idea of shwing it.

Comment: Below example when the flatlist is shown after 5 seconds
https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/disrespectful-peanut